# Calculate $\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb E(1-e^{-e^{B_t}}),$ for Brownian motion.

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

> Calculate the limit $$\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb E(1-e^{-e^{B_t}}),$$ where $B_t$ - standard Brownian motion.

$\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb E(1-e^{-e^{B_t}})=1-\lim_{t\to \infty} \mathbb E(e^{-e^{B_t}})$.

I think that next we should use the property of Brownian motion. Perhaps it is useful to know that $B_t \sim \mathcal N(0,t)$ or that $B_t \sim \sqrt t W_0$. However I have a problem to find this limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $B_t \sim \sqrt{t}\cdot X$ where $X$ follows the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, then
$$I(t):= \mathbb{E}\left(e^{-e^{B_t}}  \right)= \mathbb{E}\left(e^{-e^{\sqrt{t}\cdot X}}  \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \underbrace{e^{-e^{x\sqrt t}} \varphi(x)}_{=:f(x,t)}dx $$
where $ \varphi(x)$ the density function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

According to the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Statement), as the function $f(x,t)$ is bounded by $g(x) = \varphi(x)$( $\forall x, t$ we have  $0 \le e^{-e^{x\sqrt t}} \varphi(x) \le \varphi(x)$) which is integrable and
$$e^{-e^{x\sqrt t}}  = \mathbf{1}_{\{x\le 0\}}\cdot e^{-e^{x\sqrt t}}  + \mathbf{1}_{\{x \ge 0\}} \cdot e^{-e^{x\sqrt t}}\xrightarrow{t\to +\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{x\le 0\}}\cdot e^0 + \mathbf{1}_{\{x \ge 0\}} \cdot 0  = \mathbf{1}_{\{x\le 0\}}$$

then,
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to +\infty}I(t)&=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,t)dx \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \lim_{t\to +\infty}f(x,t)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{x\le 0\}} \cdot \varphi(x)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 \varphi(x)dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

Then the result of the initial limit expectation is equal to $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help!